# Recyclerview :- Multiple items get selectied when one item selected after scrolled

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final XContacts mContact = visibleObjects.get(position);

    holder.Name.setText(mContact.getName());

    holder.InviteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.InviteTextView.setText("INVITED");
        }

    });
}
```

`holder.Name.setText` :- Here i am names to recyclerview

`holder.InviteTextView.setOnClickListener` :- When I click on one `item[invite]`. After I scroll down multiple items are get invited without that item being clicked on.

**My problem is:**

[Abninav kashayp invited if I scroll down I get problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dALe3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerView, as the name says, is recycling views, that's why you are seeing 'INVITED' in other views.

In order to fix the issue, in onClickListener you should set a flag in your XContacts object:

```
mContact.setInvited(true);
```

Then you should change your onBindViewHolder code to also set the InviteTextView, just after setting the Name:

```
if (mContact.isInvited()) {
    holder.InviteTextView.setText("INVITED");
}
else {
    holder.InviteTextView.setText("INVITE");
}
```